# GConf Error: "Failed to contact configuration server ... 1: Not running within active session"

Tags: centos, gnumeric, ssconvert

I have installed Gnumeric in CentOS 6.5, then use `ssconvert` command to convert .xls/.xlsx file to CSV, but I still get the following error:

> $ ssconvert 
>       GConf Error: Failed to contact configuration server; some possible causes are that you need to enable TCP/IP networking for ORBit, or you
>   have stale NFS locks due to a system crash. See
>   http://projects.gnome.org/gconf/ for information. (Details -  1: Not
>   running within active session)
>       GConf Error: Failed to contact configuration server; some possible causes are that you need to enable TCP/IP networking for ORBit, or you
>   have stale NFS locks due to a system crash. See
>   http://projects.gnome.org/gconf/ for information. (Details -  1: Not
>   running within active session)
>
> ** (ssconvert:5725): WARNING **: Configured default font 'Sans 10.000000' not available, trying fallback...
>
> ** (ssconvert:5725): WARNING **: Fallback font 'Sans 10.000000' not available, trying 'fixed'...
>
> ** (ssconvert:5725): WARNING **: Even 'fixed 10' failed ??  We're going to exit now,there is something wrong with your font
>   configuration

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

As this is an old question, the answer is in case someone will get the same error (like me today on CentOS 6.8), you missed to install the Sans font:

yum install gnu-free-sans-fonts

Answer (score 1):

For docker alpine images this might help:

```
RUN apk add --update \
        msttcorefonts-installer fontconfig \
        ttf-opensans
```